# Find and replace entries in one csv file using another with bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk

Main file:

```
A B
C D
D A
G H
```

Ref file:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 G
6 H
```

New file:

```
1 2
3 4
4 1
5 6
```

I wanna do the above replacement, how can I do that using awk or some simple command line?

Comment: Hi! you should try to find a solution first, and then provide an [mvce](/help/mvce), so we can provide better answers on your issue.

Comment: Apologies, I did try to look for a solution. I ended up finding one that does replacement in a different way and it didn't have an explanation for the command line. Wanted a better answer than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[$2]=$1; next }{ $1=a[$1]; $2=a[$2] }1' reffile mainfile
```

The output:

```
1 2
3 4
4 1
5 6
```

---

- `a[$2]=$1` - capturing numbers from `reffile` into array indexed by letters (e.g. `a["A"]=1`)
- `$1=a[$1]; $2=a[$2]` - replacing letters in `mainfile` with respective numbers

Comment: Thank you! This answers it.

Comment: a quick follow up. If the two columns had the same entry, it is only replacing one and removing the other. Is that normal? For example if a row was `A A` the output comes out to be just `1`.

Comment: @Blizzard, I've just tested on `A A` record and it gave me `1 1`. Should work

Comment: Oh! I had missing values in the ref file. It works splendidly, thank you!